# Using .NET 6 with WPF and MS SQL Server. Can't connect!! :-(

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, .net-6.0

So, I'm largely new to the .net world asides some basic c# code.

For a learning project, I have to connect to a MS SQL database hosted locally to maintain persistance within a .net6 WPF app

I just can't seem to get it right!

I have to create the database Code First so I have some simple classes set up like this one:

```
namespace CapsizeRUs.Domain;

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the DbContext set up like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CapsizeRUs.Domain;


public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
        
        "data source=localhost; initial catalog=CapsizeRUs-Dev;persist security info=True; Integrated Security=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
        
            );
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
   
}
```

I've stripped things down to just the simplest class to make things clearer.

So far, everything runs until I try to add any data. If I try to do the following:

```
using (var ctx = new EntityContext())
{
    var user = new User() { Id = 0 };
    ctx.Users.Add(user);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get a connection error. I realise, I have not completed all the entries into the class and that may cause issues, I can figure all that out later but for now, I can't even get it to connect to create the database / table. I get the following:

(0x80131904): Cannot open database "CapsizeRUs-Dev" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-xxxx\xxxx'

I am guessing the problem is with the connection string. The user does exist on the MS SQL Server, I have the Server Management Studio installed which made that easy to verify:

What foolishness on my part is holding me back? I tried adding the user id into the string, maybe it's a permissions issue with that ID to start with. Is it trying to connect to the database before it's created? I though Entity framework would sort that for me. I am struggling to find implementations that directly compare to what I have been told to use.

I'm betting I've missed something silly :-(

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, A struggling .net amateur

Comment: *"`Integrated Security=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes`"* Huh? `Integrated Security` and `Trusted_Connection` are synonyms, how can the setting be both on and off at the same time?

Comment: To be honest, the "Integrated Security=False" was a shot in the dark to get things working. I have little to no understanding of the connection string, I've been trying to learn more as I go. I just tried to remove the "Trusted Connections".. It throws me out still, in fact quicker with   *(0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.*

Comment: "Integrated security" is used to enable SSPI (meaning your application will present the user identity it's running under to SQL Server for authentication).

Comment: How exactly did you create the user database side ? WIth a windows login (e.g. `CREATE LOGIN [DESKTOP-xxxx\xxxx] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]`) ? Or as a SQL Server user (e.g. `CREATE LOGIN [test] WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF`)

Comment: The next thing I tried was explicitly adding the User ID, I got a different error like so: ***(0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)*** I will try it the other way around now, removing the integrated security. Sorry I have so little understanding of the connection string or the security protocols mssql uses

Comment: To be honest, the user was already there, it comes up as a *WIndows Athentication* id in the login properties. Do I need a *SQL Server Authentication* ID?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to set up the most simple ID and Connection String possible. It's only running locally and as I get a clearer understanding of what's going on, I can add more security later :-) Unfortunately, my limited Database experience is with MySQL and PHP which is not really transferrable here :-(

Comment: For a fully local installation, a Windows Login is probably the easiest, no need to bother with any user/login shenanigans. What the other error you got was saying was that the particular communication channel your application was trying to use was not in fact listened to by SQL Server. (which is weird, because shared memory is enabled by default IIRC)

Comment: The error was saying user `DESKTOP-xxxx\xxxx` does not have access to your database `CapsizeRUs-Dev`. Did you create your database using entity framework migrations or manually using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: I see you've mention code first, so in the you should create a migrations using `add-migration [migration name]` in  Package Manager Console and EF will create migration files. Then you should run `update-database` so it will create the database and tables. If database and tables are created, check it using SQL Server Management Studio, you can then run your application. If you have issues in your connection string, it will prompt an error during `update-database`.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I think you've hit the nail on the head. I'm not understanding the Migration process properly and I'm in the proverbial 'Chicken - Egg' Scenario. I can't log into a database that doesn't exist. I need to go back and look at the Migration  and take it from there. :-)